# Add required checkbox on an Ajax Wordpress registration form

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a theme that uses ajax for a custom frontend registration form. To this, I am trying to integrate a required checkbox for terms and conditions. However, I am pulling blanks when trying to get the value on whether the checkbox is checked or not. I'm sure it has something to do with how I am using ajax.

My checkbox with name and value set:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="agreement" value="1" id="agreement">I agree to Terms & Conditions.
```

I then assign my variables to my ajax form:

```
function ajax_register_form(){           
        check_ajax_referer( 'register_ajax_nonce','security-register');   
        $user_email  =   trim( $_POST['user_email_register'] ) ;
        $user_name   =   trim( $_POST['user_login_register'] ) ;
        //add checkbox requirement
        $user_agreement   =   trim ( $_POST['agreement'] );

        if (preg_match("/^[0-9A-Za-z_]+$/", $user_name) == 0) {
            print __('Invalid username( *do not use special characters or spaces ) ','wptheme');
            die();
        }
```

Then I set a conditional for my requirement:

```
    if( $user_agreement  == ''  ) { 
        print __('Please agree to the Terms & Conditions.','wptheme');
        exit();
    }
```

The email and username variables work fine. I thought I could just create a conditional that had a value if checked or no value if not checked. However, it always passes as having no value no matter what. I have also tried setting the input value to other things like 'agree" etc..

Any guidance would be helpful.

UPDATE

I think this is the part I am missed as I don't work with ajax a lot I was missing th jquery component. I need to register my variable for the checkbox here also, correct?

```
function wptheme_register (){
   var  user_login_register =  $('#user_login_register').val(); 
   var  user_email_register =  $('#user_email_register').val(); 
   var  nonce               =  $('#security-register').val();
   var agreement = $('#agreement').val();
   var  ajaxurl             =   control_vars.admin_url+'admin-ajax.php'; 


    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: {
        'action'                    :   'ajax_register_form',
        'user_login_register'       :   user_login_register,
        'user_email_register'       :   user_email_register,
        'security-register'         :   nonce,
        'agreement' : agreement

    },
```

Comment: may b checkbox not inside the `<form></form>` also put `<input type="checkbox" required>` and try by removing `value="1"` also you can try like this `if($user_agreement  == '0' )`, if checkbox not checked, it has value `0`

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a try. I just update my question. I think because I wasn't understanding Ajax properly I was missing the jquery component.

Comment: ignore my above comment and add this in ajax `var  agreement =  $('#agreement').val();` after `var  nonce`and in `data` `'security-register'         :   nonce, 'agreement' :   agreement`

Comment: Thanks. Hmm. Before, my var to my conditional would always be empty, thus my error message would always pop. Now, it always executes no matter if checked or not. Updated again above.

Comment: I actually tried to add this: ' var agreement = ( $("#answer").is(':checked') ) ? 1 : 0;'  to the JS and I thought it would work, but no dice.

Comment: check your browser console log, if there is an error it should b there and tells you why its not working

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work, mainly because of Shehary's guidance above and a little tweak.

I set the jquery var to :

```
var agreement = ( $("#agrement").is(':checked') ) ? 1 : 0;
```

And my conditional to:

```
if( $user_agreement  == '0'  )
```

Thanks Stackoverflow!